# jQuery getJSON callback isn't triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to reproduce the simply jQuery example from the Flask docs: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/jquery/. It works fine on my local machine, but when I host it on a web server in cgi-bin, getJSON returns false. How can I correct this? Thank you!

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/_add_numbers')
def add_numbers():
    a = request.args.get('a', 0, type=int)
    b = request.args.get('b', 0, type=int)
    return jsonify(result=a + b)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>



<script type=text/javascript>
  $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};
</script>

<script type=text/javascript>
  $(function() {
    $('a#calculate').bind('click', function() {
      $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_add_numbers', {
        a: $('input[name="a"]').val(),
        b: $('input[name="b"]').val()
      }, function(data) {
        $("#result").text(data.result);
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
<h1>jQuery Example</h1>
<p><input type=text size=5 name=a> +
   <input type=text size=5 name=b> =
   <span id=result>?</span>
<p><a href=# id=calculate>calculate server side</a>
```

Comment: What's the value returned from the call to `_add_numbers` that `getJSON` makes? The "Network" tab in your browser's development tools should tell you what's going wrong

Comment: Ah, it looks like the value returned by ```_add_numbers``` is actually correct: {"result":4}, @MatsLindh.

Comment: So it seems the callback is simply not being triggered to update the text --do you have any idea why that might be?

Comment: Curiously, adding this line ```.always();``` seemed to resolve the problem... any insight?

Comment: That seems to indicate that jQuery didn't decide that the request was a success - the callback (the parameter is aptly named `success`) will only be invoked if jQuery thinks the request was successful. `always` will make it invoke the callback regardless. Could be because of the HTTP response code from the server, the content-type or anything else. Hard to say.